# C# Expose a EXE function to be invoked by DLL

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly, invoke

I have an EXE. I want to create a DLL so that the newly created DLL can invoke a method on this EXE.

This is as though the newly created DLL is a forwarding agent which accepts messages from other applications and forwards it to the EXE.

All my code is in C# and .NET 4.
I would not want to use Memory Mapped files or named pipes, I would like to use only "*function calls*".

Could you please suggest the simplest way to achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: Is the .exe itself a .NET application?

Comment: Hi Scott, yes the exe itself is a .NET application.

Answer (score 1):

The EXE assembly can be referenced by the DLL and the methods calls can be made. It technically WILL work but wouldn't be good design approach. The better approach is to have a common DLL that has the common functions and is referenced by the EXE and the new DLL.